# How does Structured Streaming execute separate streaming queries (in parallel or sequentially)?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm writing a test application that consumes messages from Kafka's topcis and then push data into S3 and into RDBMS tables (flow is similar to presented here: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html). So I read data from Kafka and then:

- each message want to save into S3
- some messages save to table A in an external database (based on filter condition)
- some other messages save to table B in an external database (other filter condition)

So I have sth like:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark
.readStream()
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
.option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2,topic3")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.load()
.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, jsonOptions).alias("parsed_value"))
```

(please notice that I'm reading from more than one Kafka topic). 
Next I define required datasets:

```java
Dataset<Row> allMessages = df.select(.....)
Dataset<Row> messagesOfType1 = df.select() //some unique conditions applied on JSON elements
Dataset<Row> messagesOfType2 = df.select() //some other unique conditions
```

and now for each Dataset I create query to start processing:

```java
StreamingQuery s3Query = allMessages
.writeStream()
.format("parquet")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest")
.option("path", "s3_location")
.start()

StreamingQuery firstQuery = messagesOfType1
.writeStream()
.foreach(new CustomForEachWiriterType1()) // class that extends ForeachWriter[T] and save data into external RDBMS table
.start();

StreamingQuery secondQuery = messagesOfType2
.writeStream()
.foreach(new CustomForEachWiriterType2()) // class that extends ForeachWriter[T] and save data into external RDBMS table (may be even another database than before)
.start();
```

Now I'm wondering:

Will be those queries executed in parallel (or one after another in FIFO order and I should assign those queries to separate scheduler pools)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will be those queries executed in parallel

Yes. These queries are going to be executed in parallel (every `trigger` which you did not specify and hence is to run them as fast as possible).

---

Internally, when you execute `start` on a [DataStreamWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter), you create a `StreamExecution` that in turn creates immediately so-called daemon `microBatchThread` (quoted from [the Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L200-L208) below):

```
  val microBatchThread =
    new StreamExecutionThread(s"stream execution thread for $prettyIdString") {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        // To fix call site like "run at <unknown>:0", we bridge the call site from the caller
        // thread to this micro batch thread
        sparkSession.sparkContext.setCallSite(callSite)
        runBatches()
      }
    }
```

You can see every query in its own thread with name:

```
stream execution thread for [prettyIdString]
```

You can check the separate threads using [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html) or [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).

Comment: I do not get the trigger point. Can you elaborate how that would make them sequential execution pls?

Comment: @thebluephantom Another question on SO, please :)